# ProGuard Maven not finding jar

Tags: java, maven, proguard

I'm trying to obfuscate my jar with pro guard but it fails with the following message:
Failed to execute goal com.github.wvengen:proguard-maven-plugin:2.0.13:proguard (default-cli) on project AdvancedMLGRush: Can't find file D:\IdeaProjects\AdvancedMLGRushOld\target\AdvancedMLGRush.jar

It can't find the jar because I have change the output directory. How can I fix this? Thank you in advance!

Maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.13</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>obfuscation-packaging</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <proguardVersion>LATEST</proguardVersion>
                            <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                            <attach>true</attach>
                            <appendClassifier>false</appendClassifier>
                            <addMavenDescriptor>true</addMavenDescriptor>
                            <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
                            <injarNotExistsSkip>true</injarNotExistsSkip>
                            <libs>
                                <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                            </libs>

                            <options>
                                <option>-keepdirectories</option>
                                <option>-keeppackagenames org.apache.maven.plugin.my.MyMojo</option>
                                <option>-keepnames class * implements org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo</option>
                                <option>-keepclassmembers class * implements org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo {
                                    private <![CDATA[<fields>]]>;
                                    private <![CDATA[<methods>]]>;
                                    }
                                </option>
                                <option>-keepparameternames</option>
                                <option>-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile</option>
                                <option>-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
                                    SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
                                </option>
                                <option>-target 1.8</option>
                                <option>-keep public class * {
                                    public protected *;
                                    }
                                </option>
                                <option>-keepclassmembernames class * {
                                    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
                                    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
                                    }
                                </option>
                                <option>-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses class * {
                                    native <![CDATA[<methods>]]>;
                                    }
                                </option>
                                <option>-keepclassmembers,allowoptimization enum * {
                                    public static **[] values();
                                    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
                                    }
                                </option>
                                <option>-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
                                    static final long serialVersionUID;
                                    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
                                    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
                                    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
                                    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
                                    java.lang.Object readResolve();
                                    }
                                </option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                        <version>LATEST</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```